# Is $\mathsf{DTIME}(n) = \mathsf{DTIME}(2n)$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines, time-hierarchy

Define $\mathsf{DTIME}(f(n))$ as the class of languages that can be accepted by a (multitape) Turing machine in time $f(n) + 1$. (The "$+ 1$" is just to simplify notation and avoid confusion.) Notice that there is no $O(\cdot)$ around $f(n) + 1$.

Is it true that $\mathsf{DTIME}(n) = \mathsf{DTIME}(2n)$?

Using the [linear speed-up theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_speedup_theorem), we can prove $\mathsf{DTIME}(2n) = \mathsf{DTIME}(1.01n)$, but can we reach $n$?

It seems that the language of palindromes is in $\mathsf{DTIME}(n)$; for related topics, see [Lipton's blog post about string algorithms](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/stringology-the-real-string-theory/)

Comment: In "[Deterministic Turing Machines in the Range between Real-Time and Linear-Time](http://cage.ugent.be/~klein/papers/turing.pdf)" I found: if $r \in T^{-1}(DTM)$ and $r'\in o(r)$ then $DTIME(n + r') \subset DTIME(n + r)$

Comment: Nice, seems to be just what I was looking for. Do you want to convert it into an answer?

Comment: interesting question but object to the redefinition of a [standard complexity class DTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) in a nonstandard way, suggest you at least call it something like DTIME' to avoid confusion

Comment: This paper maybe helpful. [Rosenberg 67] Real-Time Definable Languages
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321423

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the comment:

In "[Deterministic Turing Machines in the Range between Real-Time and Linear-Time](http://cage.ugent.be/~klein/papers/turing.pdf)" I found:

... if $r \in T^{−1}(DTM)$ and $r' \in o(r)$ then $DTIME(n+r') \subset DTIME(n+r)$ ...

Comment: What is $T^{-1}(DTM)$?

Comment: $T^{-1}(DTM)$ is the inverse of an increasing, unbounded time-constructible function $f$ ( $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_0, c' \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n \geq n_0$ we have $c f(n) \leq f(c'n)$ ). You can replace it with a honest sublinear function.